# The nuclear spins of alkali metals

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin

Looking at the different isotopes of alkali metals and their nuclear spins, I notice that nearly all of their bosonic isotopes have nuclear spin of 3/2. Surely there must be an explanation in nuclear physics (which I know very little about).

Would someone kindly explain why so many stable bosonic isotopes of alkali metal atoms have nuclear spin of 3/2?

Comment: Bosons have integer spins; you presumably mean fermionic nuclei. Do you think this is limited to alkali nuclei, or is it perhaps a feature of all odd-$A$ nuclei to prefer 3/2 to other half-integer spins?

Comment: @rob: A bosonic isotope of an alkali metal means a bosonic *atom*. For an alkali metal *atom* to be a boson, it needs half integer nuclear spin.

Comment: @rob: Also, this does not seem to be a feature of odd-A nuclei. Alkaline earth metal fermions have a variety of half-integer nuclear spins with no obvious bias toward 3/2. Boron group bosons also do not seem to have a bias toward 3/2.

Comment: Nuclear stability is, with a very few exceptions, not influenced by the electron cloud. The nuclear “shell model” has a lot of similarity with the electron shells which define the periodic table, but the nuclei with “magic proton number” are different from the noble gases with “magic electron number,” except for helium.

Comment: @rob: Thanks, but I'm not sure why you are bringing up the electron cloud. The question is simply the following: 1) Stable alkali isotopes that are bosonic atoms have half integer nuclear spin 2) Most of these nuclear spins are 3/2 ... why?

Comment: My previous comment seems to have lost a sentence that I intended. There is nothing intrinsically "alkali" about a *nucleus*; everything interesting about alkali chemistry is because the number of electrons is full-shell-plus-one. The alkali species Li, Na, K, Rb, Cs are all over the place in terms of their relationships to the filled proton and neutron shells. I would look for nuclear spin effects relative to the elements with nuclear magic numbers (oxygen, calcium, nickel, tin, lead) rather than the elements with electron magic numbers (helium, neon, and other noble gases).

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question: I think you are saying that if you look at the odd-mass nuclei of alkali metals, the most common spin is 3/2, but if you look at other odd-mass nuclei the most common spin is not 3/2. Is there a different most common spin for these non-alkali isotopes? Can you [edit] your question with data to show the prevalence?

Comment: @rob: I'm not sure why you are bringing up chemistry. Here "alkali' merely refers to a group of the Periodic Table. I am simply noting the puzzling fact that if I look at Main Group I of the Periodic Table (AKA the alkalis), and I observe the nuclear spin of the odd-mass stable isotopes, it is typically 3/2. This is not the case for Main Group II, III, etc.

Comment: @rob: Yes, I can put together some data.